# MySQL equivalent of DECODE function in Oracle

Tags: sql, mysql, database, oracle

I am trying to find an equivalent of DECODE function in MySQL. It works like this:

```
Select Name, DECODE(Age,
       13,'Thirteen',14,'Fourteen',15,'Fifteen',16,'Sixteen',
       17,'Seventeen',18,'Eighteen',19,'Nineteen',
       'Adult') AS AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

The DECODE function will compare value of column 'Age' with 13, 14, 15.. and return appropriate string value 'Thirteen', 'Fourteen'.. and if it matches with nothing, then default value of 'Adult' will be returned.

Any ideas which function in MySQL can do this job? Thanks.

CLARIFICATION: I agree using CASE is one way of achieving desired result, but I am rather looking for a ***function*** because of performance and other reasons.

Comment: A function won't be faster than the CASE statement

Comment: Mysql's ELT seems to be a DECODE alterntive: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Answer (score 61):

You can use `IF()` where in Oracle you would have used `DECODE()`.

```
mysql> select if(emp_id=1,'X','Y') as test, emp_id from emps;
```

Comment: this only works for boolean expressions, not arbitrary length cases like `DECODE()` does.

Comment: but presumably you could nest it if you wanted?

Answer (score 26):

```
Select Name, 
case 
  when Age = 13 then 'Thirteen'
  when Age = 14 then 'Fourteen'
  when Age = 15 then 'Fifteen'
  when Age = 16 then 'Sixteen'
  when Age = 17 then 'Seventeen'
  when Age = 18 then 'Eighteen'
  when Age = 19 then 'Nineteen'
  else 'Adult'
end as AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement...however why don't you just create a table with an integer for ages between 0 and 150, a varchar for the written out age and then you can just join on that

Answer (score 10):

Another MySQL option that may look more like Oracle's `DECODE` is a combination of `FIELD` and `ELT`. In the code that follows, `FIELD()` returns the argument list position of the string that matches Age. `ELT()` returns the string from `ELT`s argument list at the position provided by `FIELD()`. For example, if `Age` is `14`, `FIELD(Age, ...)` returns `2` because `14` is the 2nd argument of `FIELD` (not counting `Age`). Then, `ELT(2, ...)` returns `'Fourteen'`, which is the 2nd argument of `ELT` (not counting the `FIELD()` argument). `IFNULL` returns the default `AgeBracket` if no match to `Age` is found in the list.

```
Select Name, IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(Age,
       13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19),'Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen','Sixteen',
       'Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen'),
       'Adult') AS AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

While I don't think this is the best solution to the question either in terms of performance or readability it is interesting as an exploration of MySQL's string functions. Keep in mind that `FIELD`'s output does not seem to be case sensitive. I.e., `FIELD('A','A')` and `FIELD('a','A')` both return `1`.

Answer (score 5):

The example translates directly to:

```
Select Name, CASE Age
       WHEN 13 then 'Thirteen' WHEN 14 then 'Fourteen' WHEN 15 then 'Fifteen' WHEN 16 then 'Sixteen'
       WHEN 17 then 'Seventeen' WHEN 18 then 'Eighteen' WHEN 19 then 'Nineteen'
       ELSE 'Adult' END AS AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

which you may prefer to format e.g. like this:

```
Select Name,
       CASE Age
         when 13 then 'Thirteen'
         when 14 then 'Fourteen'
         when 15 then 'Fifteen'
         when 16 then 'Sixteen'
         when 17 then 'Seventeen'
         when 18 then 'Eighteen'
         when 19 then 'Nineteen'
         else         'Adult'
       END AS AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

Answer (score 1):

If additional table doesn't fit, you can write your own function for translation.

The plus of sql function over case is, that you can use it in various places, and keep translation logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if() in place of decode() in mySql as follows 
  This query will print all even id row.

```
mysql> select id, name from employee where id in
-> (select if(id%2=0,id,null) from employee);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers work correctly in case there are no `NULL` values involved, here's a `NULL` safe answer (because that's what Oracle's `DECODE` *really* does):

```sql
SELECT
  Name, 
  CASE
    WHEN Age <=> 13 THEN 'Thirteen'
    WHEN Age <=> 14 THEN 'Fourteen'
    WHEN Age <=> 15 THEN 'Fifteen'
    ...
  END AS AgeBracket
FROM Person
```

Might be worth noting that MySQL "compatible" RDBMS have imitated Oracle's function:

- [SingleStore has native `DECODE()` support](https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/conditional-functions/decode.html)
- [MariaDB has an Oracle mode to change `DECODE()` behaviour, or supports `DECODE_ORACLE()` for the same thing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/decode/)

Answer (score -9):

Try this:

```
Select Name, ELT(Age-12,'Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen','Sixteen',
   'Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult',
   'Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult','Adult') AS AgeBracket FROM Person
```