# Decoding fields in Mysql

Tags: mysql, decode

I want to get net amount from my mysql data field. I have tried to decode the fields like the below.. But I am getting the Error:

> "Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'decode'"

Can anybody help?

Query I have used:

```
select decode (txn_type ,'Exense',-txn_amount,txn_amount)as net_amount where id > 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL equivalent of DECODE function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706100/mysql-equivalent-of-decode-function-in-oracle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL `DECODE()` function is used for decryption, its signature is:

```
 DECODE(crypt_str,pass_str)
```

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_decode). If you want something equivalent to Oracle's `DECODE()` function, see:

[MySQL equivalent of DECODE function in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706100/mysql-equivalent-of-decode-function-in-oracle-and-intersystem-cache-database)

Your query can be rewritten as:

```
SELECT IF(txn_type = 'Expense', -txn_amount, txn_amount) AS net_amount
WHERE id > 0
```

or:

```
SELECT CASE txn_type
            WHEN 'Expense' THEN -txn_amount
            ELSE txn_amount
       END AS net_amount
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to mysql. We are using Oracle. in oracle we are using " select sum( decode (txn_type ,'Expense',-txn_amount,txn_amount)as net_amount where id > 0 " to get the result. If possible, please specify what i have to write in mysql to get the result which i have getting in Oracle.

Comment: I added the MySQL version of your query.