# How to convert Max() KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY) from Oracle to MariaDB or MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, mariadb

I'm migrate the Oracle to MariaDB. Got problem of convert the Oracle script to MariaDB script, this script can be convert to MariaDB?

This is a new server, running MariaDB 10.3.13. I've tried online convert (sqlLines) then paste code to HeidiQSQL execute and always got error.

```
SELECT o3.id,
    o3.FINISH_DATE,
    o3.START_DATE,
    o3.STEP_OWNER,
    o3.INITIAL_STATUS,
    o3.LAST_STATUS,
    o3.STEP_NAME,
    o3.STAGE_NAME,
    o3.REF_ID,
    o3.REF_STATUS,
    o3.ACTION_BY,
    o3.ELAPSED_TIME,
    DECODE (o3.STEP_NAME, '006' , 'Y' , 'N') AS IS_STP
  FROM os_historyrecord o3
  WHERE o3.id IN
    (SELECT MAX(prev.previous_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST
    ORDER BY o2.finish_date)
    FROM
      (SELECT id, stage_name, ref_id, finish_date FROM os_currentrecord
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, stage_name, ref_id, finish_date FROM os_historyrecord
      ) o2,
      (SELECT op.id,
        op.previous_id,
        op.step_index
      FROM os_historyrecord_prev op
      WHERE op.previous_id IN
        (SELECT o.id
        FROM os_historyrecord o,
          LOSA_APP app
        WHERE o.REF_ID       = app.APP_NO
        AND o.stage_name     = '003'
        AND app.product_type = 'CL'
        GROUP BY o.id
        )
      AND op.step_index = 0
      ) prev
    WHERE PREV.id       = O2.id
    AND (O2.STAGE_NAME IN '004'
    OR O2.STAGE_NAME    = '005'
    OR O2.Stage_Name    = '006')
    GROUP BY O2.Ref_Id
    );
```

I expect the MariaDB out can be same as a Oracle.

Error prompt in HeidiSQL.
[image: Execute error from MariaDB]

Comment: Please publish the error in full.AND what online converter?

Comment: You may find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706100/mysql-equivalent-of-decode-function-in-oracle

Comment: Incidentally, have you looked into partitioning?

Comment: This is not useful for me. Thanks @P.Salmon

Comment: @Strawberry, i am no idea of this one, can you explain more. Thanks

Comment: Well, you seem to have two tables holding the same type of thing. It might be more efficient to have one partitioned table instead.

Comment: Sorry @Strawberry, i still not understand. The partition i never use before.

Comment: If only there was some method for looking up concepts we don't understand

Comment: What is that construct supposed to do?  Maybe we can suggest a workaround.