# concat_ws a string based on the value of the column in the SQL query

Tags: sql, concat-ws

I am trying to concatenate values from multiple fields using `concat_ws`. One of the fields (`is_logged`) contains only the values `0` or `1`. I want to concatenate `yes` if the value of `is_logged` field is `1` and `no` otherwise.

E.g. -
`concat_ws('', month,'-', year, ',Logged-', is_logged) info`

Current output - `Dec - 2020,Logged-1`

Expected output - `Dec - 2020,Logged-Yes`

How can this be achieved?
Thanks!

Comment: are you using sql server?

Answer (score 1):

can be different in different dbms but you can do this:

```
select concat_ws('',month,'-',year,',Logged-',case is_logged when 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end) info
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26707950/10487667) -

```
concat_ws('', month,'-', year, ',Logged-',IFNULL(ELT(FIELD(is_logged,1),'Yes'),'No')) info
```